# Interface builder: File owner vs custom object

Tags: iphone, iboutlet

Let's say I create a view controller with a corresponding nib file using the wizard (file -> new)

I drag in a couple of labels of the view in IB.

I create the IBoutlets in the code, synthesize them.

Now I want to link the IBoutlets to the labels in the view.

What is the difference between

1) specifying the view controller as the file owner of the nib in IB, then dragging connections between the labels to file owner outlets

Versus

2) dragging out a "custom object" (orangish cube) in IB, specifying my view controller class name in the custom object , then only dragging connections between the labels and IBoutlets in the custom object?

Answer (score 0):

The File Owner is the already existing ViewController.
If you add a custom object to your xib file your app will create a new object for you.

You now have two ViewControllers of the same type. I can't imagine a case where you want that.

Depending on the rest of the code this can lead to many problems. Imagine a master-detail app where you pass the selected object in the MasterViewController to the DetailViewController. If the xib "creates" a new DetailViewController it won't know about the object you passed to it.